# C# Revit API Create linear dimension

Tags: c#, dimension, revit-api

I am trying to create a dimension between the left and right ends of an element in a view section as shown in the image.

[Linear dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpFd5.png)

I am using the following code to get the references of the faces by iterating the solids.

```
public static Reference ReferenciaPlanoIzquierdoElementoEnVista(View vista, Element elem)
{
    // Crea la referencia a devolver
    Reference referencia = null;

    // Crea la variable distancia
    double distancia = double.MinValue;

    // Obtiene el vector unitario que apunta hacia la izquierda de la vista
    XYZ vistaIzquierda = -vista.RightDirection.Normalize();

    // Crea las preferencias para analizar la geometría
    Options opcion = new Options();

    // Activa el cálculo de referencias a objetos
    opcion.ComputeReferences = true;

    // Crea una representación geométrica del elemento
    GeometryElement geoElem = elem.get_Geometry(opcion);

    // Recorre todos las geometrías primitivas
    foreach (GeometryObject geoObje in geoElem)
    {
        // Castea la primitiva 
        GeometryInstance geoInst = geoObje as GeometryInstance;

        // Verifica que esa geometría no sea nula
        if (geoInst != null && geoInst.IsElementGeometry)
        {
            // Asigna la geometría primitiva a la representación geométrica
            geoElem = geoInst.GetInstanceGeometry();
                
            break;
        }
    }

    // Recorre todos los solidos de la geometría
    foreach (Solid solido in geoElem.OfType<Solid>().Where<Solid>(sol => sol != null))
    {
        // Recorre todas las caras del solido
        foreach (Face cara in solido.Faces)
        {
            // Verifica que la cara no sea nula
            if (cara != null)
            {
                // Obtiene las coordenadas 3D de la cara en un punto dado
                XYZ puntoMedio = ObtenerPuntoMedioCara(cara);
                    
                // Obtiene el vector unitario normal de la cara en un punto dado
                XYZ normal = ObtenerVectorNormalCara(cara).Normalize();

                // Verifica que la normal sea paralela a la vista derecha
                if (normal.CrossProduct(vistaIzquierda).IsZeroLength() && normal.IsAlmostEqualTo(vistaIzquierda))
                {
                    // Distancia del punto medio de la cara al baricentro del elemento en el sentido del vector derecha de la vista
                    double distanciaACara = Math.Abs(DistanciaBaricentroElementoACara(vista, elem, cara));

                    // Verifica que la distancia sea mayor
                    if (distanciaACara > distancia)
                    {
                        // Asigna la nueva distancia
                        distancia = distanciaACara;

                        // Asigna la referencia de la cara
                        referencia = cara.Reference;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return referencia;
}
```

And this code to create a dimension.

```
public static Dimension CrearCotaHorizontalAbajoParaElemento(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox combo, List<DimensionType> estilosCotas,
                                                                Document doc, View vista, Element elem)
{
    // Obtiene el DimensionType de la etiqueta seleccionada
    DimensionType dimType = estilosCotas.FirstOrDefault(eti => eti.Name == combo.SelectedItem.ToString());

    // Crea un arreglo con las referencias
    ReferenceArray ArregloRef = new ReferenceArray();

    // Obtiene el vector unitario que apunta hacia la derecha de la vista
    XYZ vistaDerecha = vista.RightDirection.Normalize();

    // Crea una caja de sección del elemento
    BoundingBoxXYZ bb = elem.get_BoundingBox(vista);

    // Agrega las referencias del plano
    ArregloRef.Append(ReferenciaPlanoIzquierdoElementoEnVista(vista, elem));
    ArregloRef.Append(ReferenciaPlanoDerechoElementoEnVista(vista, elem));
        
    // Crea las coordenadas de la linea
    XYZ x1 = new XYZ(bb.Min.X, bb.Min.Y, bb.Min.Z);
    XYZ x2 = x1.Add(vistaDerecha);

    // Crea la linea temporal
    Line linea = Line.CreateBound(x1, x2);

    // Crea la cota temporal
    Dimension cota = doc.Create.NewDimension(vista, linea, ArregloRef, dimType);

    // Crea una caja de sección del elemento
    BoundingBoxXYZ bbCota = cota.get_BoundingBox(vista);

    // Obtiene la altura del texto
    double zCota = Math.Abs(bbCota.Min.Z - cota.LeaderEndPosition.Z);

    // Mueve la cota hacia abajo
    ElementTransformUtils.MoveElement(doc, cota.Id, new XYZ(0, 0, -zCota));

    return cota;
}
```

I draw on the posts of Jeremy Tammik, who talks about two ways to get referrals. I chose the first way which is iterating.

https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/02/dimension-walls-by-iterating-faces.html
https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/02/dimension-walls-using-findreferencesbydirection.html

But then he throws me a poster saying the references are not correct and the dimension should be removed.

[One or more dimension references are or have become invalid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgKf7.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are retrieving the symbol geometry. You probably need to use the instance geometry instead, as discussed in The Building Coder article on [References to Symbol versus Instance Geometry](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/04/references-in-symbol-versus-instance-geometry.html).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Jeremy.
I changed the "GetSymbolGeometry" method to "GetInstanceGeometry" as discussed in The building Coder forum and added the "IncludeNonVisibleObjects = true" property in option.
But it keeps throwing the same error.

Comment: Implement it manually via user interface and analyse the results in the database using RevitLookup. Then, implement API code to generate the same results: https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/01/virtues-of-reproduction-research-mep-settings-ontology.html#3